# How to write some LINQ which excludes related records in a link table?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have 2 tables

```
Client
ClientReport
```

I need to write some LINQ that lists all Clients that are not in the ClientReport table ie I need to list all Clients not associated with a particular report.

This is my starting point:

```
 var ClientList = db.StdClient.ToList();
```

Many thanks.

EDIT:

Sorry forgot one important requirement and that is that the filter needs to be report specific. ReportId is fed in as a parameter into the Action

EDIT2:

```
var ClientList = db.StdClient
                     .Where(c => !db.StdClientReport
                                     .Any(cr=>(
                                        (cr.StdClientId == c.Id) 
                                         && (cr.ReportId==ReportId)
                                               )
                                          )
                            ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is assuming that there is a one-to-many relation between `Client` and `ClientReport` via either a navigation property on `Client` and/or a `ClientId` property on `ClientReport`.

If there is a navigation property from `Client` to `ClientReport`:

```
var clientList = db.Client.Where(c => !c.ClientReports.Any());
```

or

```
int id = 7;  // report ID we're looking for
var clientList = db.Client.Where(c => !c.ClientReports
                                        .Any(cr => cr.ReportId == id)
                                );
```

if it's specific to one report ID.

Otherwise

```
var clientList = db.Client.Where(c => !db.StdClientReport
                                         .Any(cr=>cr.ClientId == c.Id)
                                );
```

Comment: Yes I do have a nav property, and it is a one to many.... so trying it now. Thanks for the prompt reply.

Comment: Sorry forgot one important requirement and that is that the filter needs to be report specific. ReportId is fed in as a parameter into the Action.

Comment: `cr => cr.ClientId == c.Id && cr.ReportId == reportIdParam`

Comment: Thanks Gert, I think we arrived at the same point at the same time :) However it is good to know that I am on the right route. Only question is that I do have nav properties and I do have a one to many table so I could use "D Stanley"'s  first option, but not sure how to tweak or is it just a matter of putting your condition into the Any ()?

Comment: @DStanley, a huge thank you. I think SO is so brilliant with such special folk. Learning loads here.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly also use `.Except` but i've not tested it

Something like

`var noReport = ClientList.Except(ClientReportList);`